# The proper way to include variable with sources from .cmake file to CMakeList.txt

Tags: variables, path, cmake, include

I have the following CMake problem.

The structure of my project is:

```
Project
--- libs
------ lib1
---------CmakeLists.txt
------ lib2
---------lib2.cmake
---------file1.c
---------file2.c
--- src
...
```

In my `lib2.cmake` I have:

```
set(LIB2_SOURCES
        file1.c
        file2.c
        )
```

And I want to use `${LIB2_SOURCES}` in my lib1 `CMakeList.txt`:

```
include(../lib2/lib2.cmake)
set(LIB1_SOURCES
        ....
        )

add_library(media SHARED ${LIB1_SOURCES} ${LIB2_SOURCES})
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot find source file:
file1.c
```

If I change my `lib2.cmake` and fix the path like that:

```
set(LIB2_SOURCES
        ../lib2/file1.c
        ../lib2/file2.c
        )
```

It works. But that's not a good way for me.

I can move `lib2.cmake` into the `lib1` directory, but this is also not a good way for me.

So what is the proper way to deal with this include? Is there any way to include `lib2.cmake` without losing the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have paths which do not depend on the current directory, use absolute paths:

```
set(LIB2_SOURCES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/file1.c
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/file2.c
)
```

[`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) is the directory containing the CMake file currently being processed (which will be `Project/libs/lib2` in your case when processing `lib2.cmake`).

However, instead of defining sources like this, you might also want to look into giving `lib2` a proper `CMakeLists.txt` and defining an [object library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) in it, and then adding that object library into the `media` library.

Comment: Thank you @Angew. Thats is what I've searching for. I know how to do the job with library, but in this project I have to build lib2 inside lib1.

Comment: @DustBG A CMake object library is not a library in the normal sense. It's just CMake's name for a collection of object files which will be linked into whichever target you specify. I don't know the details of your requirements, but object libraries are in general very close to "building the sources directly inside the consuming binary."

Comment: yes, I know what are you mean, but in my case It is better to use ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}.

Comment: yes, I know what are you mean, but in my case It is better to use ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}. I'm segmenting lib2 sources into several segments with intetntion to use only the sources I need in my lib1. That's handy when I build lib1, because I can choose what I want and I don't need to link other lib. With library I have to define several libraries in lib2 and then use them in lib1 but I'll need sources too. So ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} is perfect.